# Agregue el método para insertar al final de un nodo un numero pero al ejecutarlo e ingresar el numero se termina el programa

Tags: java

Este es el código que me cierra el programa, el programa da el error cuando tengo ingresado nodos anteriormente, simplemente después de ingresar el numero se cierra el panel y no me lleva al menú.Solo se sigue ejecutando sin llevarme al menú.

```
public void insertfinal(int dato) {

    if (cabeza == null) {

        node nuevo = new node(dato);

        cabeza = nuevo;

    } else {

        node nuevo = new node(dato);

        node temporal = cabeza;

        while (temporal.sig != null) {

            temporal = temporal.sig;
        }
        temporal.sig = nuevo;

    }

}
```

Comment: Reelabora la pregunta porque no se ve relación entre el código y lo que preguntas. Quizás ampliando el código se pueda entender mejor.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.